# What type and size of wire to run to my garage

Tags: electrical

I have a garage that is about 150 feet from my house I am going to run a sub-panel to. I will have several plug in outlets, lights, air compressor and welder. What type and size of wire and service andbreaker size do you recomend?

Comment: How many HP is the air compressor, and what's the nameplate current and duty cycle rating on your welder?  Also, how hard is it to trench from the house to the garage?

Comment: Whatever advice you get here, you should have checked and confirmed by a qualified person local to you for your situation - you may have missed something.